# Determine the probability that triples of the digits coincide in $2$ numbers.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Determine the probability that in two numbers, consisting of six decimal digits, exactly the triples of the digits coincide. For example $96\color{red}{352}1$ and $478\color{red}{352}.$ Consider two options when the digits in the number can be the same and when not. You use 0 as a prefix.

In case the digits in the number cannot be the same, I made such a solution, but I'm not sure how correct it is.

We have $4$ variants of placing $3$ digits in $6$-digit numbers and $10^6$ options of permutations, so the probability that $3$ digits will go together in $6$-digit numbers is $\frac{4*10^3}{10^6}=0.004$

For two numbers it will be $0.004^2$

I do not know if this is correct and I do not know what to do if the digits in the number can be the same. I would be glad if you can help.

Comment: Just a few questions for clarification: 1. Where does this problem come from? 2. Can I use 0 as prefix? 3. are 123456 and 123478 considered to coincide? (Exactly 3 digits coincide, or at least 3 digits?)

Comment: @Pieter21: 1. Found it in one book. I try to understand probability theory for university.
2. Yep. 
3. Exactly 3 digit coincide.

Answer (score 1):

In the case where the digits in the number can be the same, the calculation can be simplified by just taking $123456$ as the first number, and calculate how many 'second' numbers share a triplet.

Digit $0$ may require to be treated as a special case, depending on how you define your question exactly.

Indeed, $123456$ forms $4$ triplets, however, the number of $6$ digit numbers with different digits is not $10^6$, but $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5$.

Also, you have to take into account that each of the triplets can be completed in many ways ($7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5$).

And you may need to correct the formula with the inclusion/exclusion method, to prevent double-counting of quadruplets.

---

After your clarification: in case of exactly $3$ (different) digits coincide and I can use $0$ at will, I think this is the solution:

Given $6$ digit string $123456$, count how many $6$ digit strings (fraction of the total for the probability) coincide in exactly $3$ places.

This means we have to count digit strings of the forms $123def$, $a234ef$, $ab345f$, $abc456$, where also each of $a,b,c,d,e,f$ can not be equal to $1,2,3,4,5,6$. (This also assumes that $132456$ and $123456$ should NOT be counted as a match, because 4 digits, though not consecutive, match.)

This can be done with combinatorics, but it still is not really easy.